# How to Parse Wikipedia dumps to create links graph?

Tags: parsing, graph, hyperlink, dump, wikipedia

I am looking for a way to parse wikipedia dumps and retrieve the hyper-links found in each page. My main objective is create a directed-graph on possible paths for going from one wikipedia page to another.

For example: The page definition of "Dog" has a link to "Canis lupus". So I would have a 
Dog-> Canis Lupus as output.

PS: I would prefer python libraries if there are any.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way would be to use the dump that already contains information about links between pages: pagelinks.sql. To use it, you would import it into a MySQL database and then you can access that database from any language. To make sense of the data in that dump, you will also need to import page.sql.

Answer (score -2):

Since, you are trying to deal with Graph Theory, you will need two things -

- Production of Graph
- Implementation and Storage of Graph

**Production**

Probably you will try to use XML dumps from wikimedia, to go for your purpose.
The best solution, i would suggest is to use some kind of parsing script to extract out links from documents.

**Implementation**

To store your **huge** graph, you would have to store the output of script in some kind of **Graph Database**. Have a look here for some popular ones [here](http://readwrite.com/2011/04/20/5-graph-databases-to-consider).

Thus, the process is simple. Your script will parse the docs, one by one and store the result in Graph Database, which you can later use.

Comment: XML dumps are not a good option if all you want are links between pages.